# How to retrieve path from Spark DataFrame and then use it in spark.read?

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, pyspark

Is it possible to have retrieve file path as a string from PySpark data frame and pass it to spark.read.parquet("path")?

I have been trying to do so but I keep getting an error that Column is not iterable.

Many thanks!

Comment: Please provide an example of what you have tried so far.

Comment: do you mean like [`input_file_name`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.input_file_name) ?

Comment: Expected output would be really helpful here.